# SQL Server Query execution plan

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, sql-execution-plan

I am trying to learn about optimizing databases and queries. I have a test table `Objednavka`, that has a foreign key attribute `ODIS`. In this database, queries like

```
SELECT * FROM Objednavka WHERE ODIS = 123
```

are frequent, so I created an index like this

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX Objednavka_ODIS_index ON Objednavka (ODIS)
```

I then looked at the plan of the query I mentioned and this is what I see:

[image: query plan]

Can someone please explain why do I have the `Index Seek` and `Key Lookup` operations performed in parallel, then joined using Nested Loops? From what I learned, I thought that the `Index Seek` should be performed **first**, so that the engine finds the location of the row that contains (the indexed) `ODIS` attribute in the index, and then it should retrieve the whole data using `Key Lookup`, when it already knows the location, or am I wrong?

Comment: If you don't get your answer here, you may have more luck on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: So I am not an expert, but, I believe it is doing the key lookup as it can't get all the columns to satisfy the query, so it needs to go to the PK to be able to return them. If you removed `SELECT *` and did `SELECT ODIS` you should see it disappear. Take a look here: https://sqlespresso.com/2019/04/03/whats-a-key-lookup/

Comment: What you explained is exactly what it is doing.  The index seek is done first to populate the outer table.  It then sends those rows to the nested loop which will do a key lookup for the data it needs for each row using a Key lookup. As each row comes back from the Key Lookup the Nested Loop merges it together and sends it on.  This process continues until the outer table runs out of rows to send to the Nested Loop Join.

Comment: @JMabee I see, so I just didn't get the idea of the purpose of Nested Loops here. Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: In addition to @JMabee comment: the operations performed in parallel because Nested Loop operator is not a blocking one, so it will be sending rows to a next operator while it will still be receiving rows from the Index Seek and Key lookup operators.

Answer (score 0):

non clustered index has the PK columns added to it automatically by SQL Server. The index seek is to seek the index b-tree for the value(s) you provided for the indexed column(s) and the result is the PK values (or RIDs if your table is a heap). If all the columns you queried are part of the indexed columns, which is called a covering index, you query is done because SQL server can get all the information from the b-tree. If you need to return other columns not in the index, SQL server needs to find the data of the record using the PK, which is the key-lookup part.